# Crashing ListView.builder

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to set up a search page in a Flutter app. This widget presents a search field, monitors what the user is typing, and updates a list of suggested hits with every change in the search field. The relevant snippet is here:

```dart
List<Text> suggestList = [new Text('')];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Form(
        child: new TextFormField(
          // _controller listens for changes and updates suggestList
          controller: _controller, 
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Search here'),
          onSaved: (str) => print(str),
        ),
      ),
      new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => suggestList[index],
        itemCount: suggestList.length,
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

This widget crashes with an error message that is pages long, but includes this text that suggests my error is a layout issue. I am new to Flutter and Dart and unable to really apply the advice here meaningfully to my problem.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.
In this case, a vertical
viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. 
This situation
typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another 
scrollable widget.
If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no 
need to use a viewport because
there will always be enough vertical space for the children. 
In this case, consider using a Column
instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property 
(or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

In the snippet below, I try to simulate the effect I want by presenting a succession of Text widgets:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Form(
        child: new TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Search here'),
          onSaved: (str) => print(str),
        ),
      ),
      // Present the two first items manually as Text widgets
      suggestList[0],
      suggestList.length > 1 ? suggestList[1] : new Text('...'),
    ],
  );
}
```

This works perfectly but looks ugly and is clearly a hack that I do not want in the final app. Also I have confirmed that my logic is working perfectly -- I have checked that `suggestList` is always populated with at least one `Text` widget suitable for display. Any ideas on how to repair the ListView approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just build the Column children like this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> columnChildren = [
      new Form(
        child: new TextFormField(
          // _controller listens for changes and updates suggestList
          //controller: _controller,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Search here'),
          onSaved: (str) => print(str),
        ),
      )
    ];
    columnChildren.addAll(suggestList);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: columnChildren,
      ),
    );
  }
```

or better still just keep the suggestList as a List

```
  List<String> suggestList = [
    'hello',
    'world',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> columnChildren = [
      new Form(
        child: new TextFormField(
          // _controller listens for changes and updates suggestList
          //controller: _controller,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Search here'),
          onSaved: (str) => print(str),
        ),
      )
    ];
    columnChildren.addAll(suggestList.map((s) => new Text(s)).toList());
```

Alternatively, wrap the ListView in an Expanded

```
  body: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Form(
        child: new TextFormField(
          // _controller listens for changes and updates suggestList
          //controller: _controller,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Search here'),
          onSaved: (str) => print(str),
        ),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => new Text(wordList[i]),
          itemCount: wordList.length,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

This allows an infinite scrolling list below a fixed Form.

Comment: Thanks, @Richard Heap, this worked like a charm. Any idea why the ListBuilder approach was wrong?

Comment: You have one vertically laid out Widget inside another. So you can either put everything into the Column or, alternatively, return the Form as the zero index of the list (though I imagine you don't want the form to scroll off the top). ListBuilder is ideal for long, scrolling lists, but it feels like you will always have a short list of suggestions.

Comment: Added a way to have a scrolling list below a fixed form.

Comment: Thanks, these not only solved my problem but help me understand the underlying mechanics. Much appreciated. I especially like the Expanded method because it allows a single point of formatting each of the component items in the List.